# Goal in Google analytics for wizards - repeated steps

Tags: google-analytics, goal-tracking

My goal consist of 5 steps. Everything works fine when user completes wizard without validation error, but if he returns to same step twice, goal don't get completed and Google analytics registers that as exit from wizard.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This should not be the case as funnels are measured for a particular "session".  As long as a user visits all the URLs in the funnel and the Goal URL *in the same session*, then a Goal should be recorded.

Here are a few things to consider:

Are you sure that the user actually visits all the funnel stage URLs?
Is there a chance that the user ended a session (30 minutes) before moving on?
Is the form an AJAX form which does not register page views with Google Analytics?

Comment: No, 4th step can be skipped if user is logged in, but no exits I can see on this step.